# MVC of a button to implement different types of button.Looping of the button element doesnot display all the elements in div

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, event-handling, javascriptmvc

I want to implement MVC of a button. I have created a button using
    `var btn = {btnElem : document.createElement('button')} ;` 
now i want to inherit this button into different types of buttons like arthimetic or logical button. so I used this btn object to get the arthimetic button `var parent = Object.create(btn); 
var arthButn = {btnElem : parent.btnElem};`
. Now I want to display arthButn s looping from 0-9 numbers.
But it only shows one button.

```
    buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
arthButn.btnElem.innerHTML = i;
buttonContainer.appendChild(arthButn.btnElem);
}
```

If i use document.createElement('button') in place of arthButn.btnElem it works fine. 
But in this approach, the multiple elements are not appended to the buttonContainer div. Buttons are replacing one on the other and only one button is shown.

Other issue is that I want to append event handler to the arthbtn on its controller file. 
So how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not creating 10 button elements as you expect, you are creating only one.

When you create the base prototype object

```
var btn = { btnElem: document.createElement('button') }
var parent = Object.create(btn);
```

you create a single DOM element. Then you create an object which uses the `btn` object as a prototype

```
var arthBtn = { btnElem: parent.btnElem }
```

Note that `arthBtn.btnElem` is equal to `parent.btnElem` which is equal to `btn.btnElem` by reference. So, in your loop, you are modifying the `innerHTML` of the same DOM button element, and then appending that same element to the container.

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/oz0ppkm5/. Instead of having a prototype property, use a prototype method which returns a new DOM element every time it's called.

**EDIT**: This fiddle better illustrates how you could achieve inheritance: https://jsfiddle.net/o52mn65q/.

Comment: if I want to add event listener to the arthBtn then how can I give in the controller , so that it will be applied to all the buttons?

Comment: If i add click event in the loop for each instance it works. But i want to assign the click function on the arthBtn controller only once and it should be appended to all the buttons . arthBtn.btnElem().addEventListener('click',function(){..},false) .  How can i do this

Comment: Here is a modified fiddle illustrating how this could be done: https://jsfiddle.net/235ed0br/. I've shown how you can define handlers in the controller class (`click` handler) or per-instance (`mouseover` handler).